# window.addEventListener is fired multiple times

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

Receiving data via addEventLister to my aura component and do some actions based on it, refer to the code below:

```
window.addEventListener("message", $A.getCallback(function (event) {
 try{
        if(typeof event.data['cat'] != 'dog') {
            //opens a pop-up modal
            //executes some other actions}
 catch (error){}
 }), false);
```

Suppose, I've these codes in my compA.

- When data is passed to compA for the first time -> Pop-up modal is opened once (which is expected)
- But, I move to another component for example compB and come back to compA again -> Pop-up modal is opened twice. (expected is always once).

So, for some reason, eventListener is firing twice instead of one when I try second time. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This symptom is indicative that you've registered the same listener more than once. You must remember to deregister events when your component unloads to prevent his problem. This is done with [aura:valueDestroy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:valueDestroy/documentation).

```
<aura:handler name="destroy" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doDestroy}" />
```

Further, because of how these things work, you'll need to remember to store the function reference somewhere. Here's a full example.

## template

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:handler name="destroy" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doDestroy}" />
```

---

## controller

```
doInit: function(c, e, h) {
  h.doInit(c);
},
doDestroy: function(c, e, h) {
  h.doDestroy(c);
}
```

---

## helper

```
doInit: function(c) {
  if(!this.eventHandler) {
    this.eventHandler = $A.getCallback(this.handleMessage.bind(this, c));
    window.addEventListener('message', this.eventHandler);
  }
},
doDestroy: function(c) {
  if(this.eventHandler) {
    window.removeEventListener('message', this.eventHandler);
    delete this.eventHandler;
  }
},
handleMessage: function(c, event) {
  // Do something with event, you can use c as a reference to the registered component
}
```

Note that this is just one possible solution. If you need to know which component of multiple instances is loaded, you might need a more complicated framework.

You must always remember to unregister whatever you register when using window.addEventListener in an Aura or LWC component on the appropriate removal hook (aura:valueDestroy and disconnectedCallback, respectively).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm having difficulties understanding the eventHandler. Could you please modify the code adapting to my implementation? Thank you.

Comment: Please define the eventHandler, I didn't get it. Thank you.

Comment: @HasanOnM It's just a variable stored on the Helper object to maintain a reference to the original method (which is required to unbind it later).

Comment: Assume that I've written the code I mentioned in the doInit of controller class. And, all the methods are inside controller class, in this case, how should I implement? I can't actually change the current implementation. Could you please share your thought or any alternate solution which avoids the helper class and adapts with the code I mentioned ?

Comment: @HasanOnM You could try storing the event handler in `window.onMessageHandler` instead of `this.eventHandler`, and then just store it there directly, but I'm not sure if this is considered global storage, so it may not work correctly. No harm in trying, though.

Comment: The issue still exists, I've used the following code instead of destroy:
<aura:handler event="aura:locationChange" action="{!c.doDestroy}" />
Thank you for your help, I've built the solution based on your answer, it's working fine now.